# POST JSON file for UrlFetch payload

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, urlfetch

I'm trying to POST JSON data from my Google Drive JSON file using Google Apps Script and UrlFetchApp.
When I pass in the file's JSON string directly as a variable in the script, it works.  I am missing something when trying to download the JSON file first to get the string or object.  I looked at JSON.stringify docs for an example using a file but no luck.  All the examples are using strings that are present in the script itself.

Here is an example of the JSON file contents:

```
{
  "TotalAmt": 50.0, 
  "BillEmail": {
    "Address": "my@email.com"
  }, 
  "CustomerMemo": {
    "value": "Thank you for your business and have a great day!"
  }
}
```

Here is my POST request:

```
var myJSONfile = "https://drive.google.com/someJSONFILE.json"

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      muteHttpExceptions : true,
      payload: JSON.stringify(myJSONfile),
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json'
         }
    });
```

Tried passing in JSON file directly and POST call did not work.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I'm trying to POST JSON data from my Google Drive JSON file using Google Apps Script and UrlFetchApp.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file first to extract its content into the variable `myJSONfile` over using url.

Overall the rest of your code should work.